# Meaning of ideal membrane

Tags: waves, vibrations

I'm studying  from a mathematical point of view the bidimensional vibrating membrane.

How can I define an ideal membrane? What are the assumptions when I say 'ideal'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a mathematical point of view, an ideal drum means that it is governed by the wave equation, in which the wave speed depends only on the tension at the boundary, the thickness and the density of the membrane ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibrations_of_a_circular_membrane#The_problem)).

From a physical point of view, it means that the restoring force is generated by the tension at the boundary, and have the same assumptions as an [ideal string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibrating_string#Derivation).
You can try to imagine this as a bunch of small links of a chain, that move only in the vertical direction, and transform only vertical forces between each other.

See also [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/141741/what-is-the-meaning-of-pre-tension-for-a-stiff-membrane/141743).