# What is the meaning of pre-tension for a stiff membrane?

Tags: eigenvalue, vibrations, solid-mechanics

**On one hand**, I know that the tighter a drum head is stretched, the higher its natural frequencies. This relation is [given by](http://www.comsol.com/model/download/186977/models.sme.vibrating_membrane.pdf):

$$f_{ij}=\frac{k_{ij}}{2\pi R}\sqrt{\frac{T_0}{h\rho}}$$

where $k_{ij}$ are [roots of the Bessel function](http://wwwal.kuicr.kyoto-u.ac.jp/www/accelerator/a4/besselroot.htmlx) of the first kind, $R$ is the membrane radius and $T_0$ is the pre-tension.

**On the other hand**, if my membrane is a stiff solid that is clamped to edges of a cavity, no pre-tension is required to produce frequency-response when a disturbance is introduced. Even if we neglect the induced pre-tension by gravity, we would still expect our stiff membrane to respond to an impulse, because tension will be generated "internally" upon deflection due to the impulse (see also: "[Chladni plate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Bowing_chladni_plate.png)", which has free boundary conditions).

However, I cannot use $T_0=0$ in the equation above, since it provides only the trivial solution. So what is the meaning of pre-tension for a stiff membrane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use that formula for a stiff plate - you have a fundamentally different situation.

In the stiff plate, the restoring elastic force comes from the stress arising from the strain induced elastic deformation of the plate's material. This is related to the materials' modulusses (Young's, Shear and Bulk Modulusses) and Poisson ratio. See how these ratios do NOT appear in your formula.

In the stretched membrane, on the other hand, the material is assumed to be infinitely flexible and flimsy. At rest, all the tension is in the membrane's plane. As the membrane is deformed sideways, there is a component of this roughly constant tension opposing the deformation: a two dimensional analogy of the stretched, infinitely flimsy string. Other than its being infintely flimsy, *no other material properties matter* in this analysis.

I can't give you a formula for what you need, but you would have to work out orfind the analogy for [Euler-Bernoulli beam theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Bernoulli_beam_theory) or [Timoshenko beam theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timoshenko_beam_theory). Timoshenko Beam theory applies to the stiff beam, and this is quite a different theory to that of the [Stretched flimsy string](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/waves/string.html).

Comment: these are good observations. why in fact the young modulus is not present in the flimsy string equation?

Comment: @Sparkler I would find a derivation of the flimsy string wave equation if you don't know how this is done. To first order, the tension in the string stays constant. It will rise slightly under deformation, in which case the Young's modulus will give you the rise, but the assumption is that this is small. It *could* be used to calculate the tension in the string if you knew the strain in the string. But most often you're given the tension $T$ - you apply it through a known weight over a pulley, for example, $T$ stays constant to an excellent approximation unless the waves are truly huge ...

Comment: @Sparkler .... Now, as the string moves sideways (DRAW THIS for a tiny length of string and the forces on it from its neighbours), the net force on it is the sideways component of the $T$ tangent to it: in a length $\Delta L$ this sideways component is $\Delta(\tan\theta\,T) = -\Delta(\partial_x\,y\,T)\approx T\,\partial_x^2\,y\Delta L$, where $x$ is along the string's nominal direction and $y$ its sideways displacement. So, by Newton II, if the string has linear density $\sigma$, we get $m\,a = -\Delta L\,\sigma \,\partial_t^2\,y = -T\,\partial_x^2\,y\Delta L$, whence the D'Alembert wave ....

Comment: ... wave equation, with speed $c^2 = T/\sigma$. Think about this carefully.

Comment: yes, so to my understanding, the [vibrating string formulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibrating_string) is an artificial/simplified way of representing elasticity as a constant (external) tension force. so if I assume small deflections of the membrane, I could convert the internal stress in the membrane into an effective/approximate pre-tension, and use the simple equation for $f_{ij}$?

Answer (score 0):

One should differentiate between [ideal membrane vibration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibrations_of_a_circular_membrane), in which the vibration is described by a wave equation, and [plate/shell theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plate_theory) (in which the [vibration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibration_of_plates) is described by more complex approaches, such as [Kirchhoff–Love plate theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%E2%80%93Love_plate_theory) and [Mindlin–Reissner plate theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mindlin%E2%80%93Reissner_plate_theory)).

As @wetsavannaanimal-aka-rod-vance pointed out, the main difference between a "membrane" and a "plate" is that the restoring force in a membrane originates in the tension at the boundary ("pre-tension"), whereas the restoring force in a plate originates in the material properties $E, \nu$ etc.

Generally speaking, in the real world, both pre-tension and material properties influence the vibrational behaviour of a given structure, and it's up to one's needs which model/theory should be used in each situation.